# Ping.sendAsync does not work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ping

i'm using ping class and SendAsync method in my webapp(asp.net)
but i'm getting this error :

> An exception occurred during a Ping request.

the inner exception is :

> here : System.InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.
>      at System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.OperationStarted()
>      at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(Object userSuppliedState)
>      at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendAsync(IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options, Object userToken)

when i using exactly same code in winform app it works fine.

here is my code :

```
public static Ping pi = new Ping();
public static byte[] myb = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x41,0x43 };
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pi.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(pi_PingCompleted);
    int i = 1;
    object r = pi.SendAsync("192.168.1." + i.ToString(), 2000, myb); // here the error happining
}
public void pi_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs ev)
{
    PingReply pr = ev.Reply;
    Response.Write(ev.Reply.ToString());

}
```

i handled All Exceptions that may occure but won't help.

can any one tell me what i'm doing wrong or what i missed?
tanx

Comment: What's the InnerException?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An exception occurred during a Ping request.

Comment: What's the InnerException?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SendPingAsync` instead. `SendAsync` is using an [older asynchronous API design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx), and you should use the [newer asynchronous API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) for ASP.NET.

Comment: thank you Stephen but it's not the solution. what i figured out from inner exception is mark the page with Page Async="true". but if you want to use the ping async through ajax call the errors comes back. for solving this i create new thread and put the code there and started the thread via ajax call.

Comment: @YousefMostafayi: Using threads like that is unsafe on ASP.NET. The proper solution is to use `SendPingAsync` and `await` the returned task. This, in turn, will require you to mark the page `Async`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Where on this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=netcore-3.1) does it advise you to use `SendPingAsync` instead? I'll save you the trouble. It doesn't. In fact the only example of calling it asynchronously makes use of `SendAsync`.

Comment: @Ash: The Microsoft reference documentation generally tries not to be opinionated; they describe what you *can* do, not what you *should* do. The fact that `SendAsync` instead of `SendPingAsync` is used as the asynchronous example is most likely because those docs are out of date. Feel free to submit a PR; all the MS docs are open source these days.